# Как сделать sum(x) до определенного значения в результате выборки?

Tags: sql, postgresql

Есть таблица с полями:
`id (int), amount (numeric), is_stop (bool), created_at (timestamptz)`

```
SELECT SUM(mo.amount)
FROM orders.mq_order mo ORDER BY mo.id, mo.created_at
```

Нужно сделать так, чтобы в `sum()` посчитались только те записи, которые идут до первой записи со значением поля `is_stop`, `true` (включительно)

Если таблица `mq_order` имеет такие данные:

```
1 10 false дата какая-то
23 15 false дата какая-то
31 9 false дата какая-то
54 10 true дата какая-то
565 4123 false дата какая-то
6565 323 false дата какая-то
54545 3434 false дата какая-то
```

Тогда результат функции должен быть 44

Такой способ кажется плохим:

1. делаю запрос типа:

select id from mq_order where is_stop == true order by id, created_at limit 1

2. `sum(x) where id <= id из прошлого запроса`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
SELECT SUM(amount)
FROM mq_order 
WHERE id <= ( SELECT FIRST_VALUE(id) OVER (ORDER BY id) fv
              FROM mq_order 
              WHERE is_stop )
```

https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_12&fiddle=1384714ec3e1c66093e963f8566a16b3